# How to change android DragShadow when drag events are fired?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-3.0-honeycomb

I want to change the color of the drag shadow when ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED event is fired. How to do this? The drag & drop framework didn't provide any reference to the shadow.

Comment: Hey did you found any solutions for it? I also want to do same.